# Tor blocked due to invalid SSL certificate

Tags: censorship, pluggable-transports, certificate

My Censor generally blocks Tor, so I decided to use obfuscated bridges in the hope that that would work. But either the pluggable transport does this ...

```
>13/06/2014 10:03:26 AM.374 [NOTICE] Pluggable Transport proxy (fte exec Tor\Pluggable Transports\fteproxy --managed) does not provide any needed transports and will not be launched.
```

... or it tells me that the certificate is wrong. Now my network uses their own certificates for all HTTPS or SSL connections! How do I fix it? The block is netbox blue.